# Custom validator gets time object but needs the string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails 4.1.6 project, I have a database table with a timestamp:

```
create_table "jobs", force: true do |t|
  ...
  t.timestamp "run_time",             limit: 6
  ...
end
```

The model includes a custom validation for that field:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates :run_time, iso_time: true
  ...
end
```

The custom validator is:

```
require "time"

class IsoTimeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    p [value.class, value] #DEBUG
    errors = []
    unless Iso_8601.valid?(value)
      errors << "is not an ISO-8601 time"
    else
      if options[:time_zone]
        if Iso_8601.has_time_zone?(value) != options[:time_zone]
          errors << [
            "should",
            ("not" unless options[:time_zone]),
            "have time zone"
          ].compact.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
    set_errors(record, attribute, errors)
  end

  private

  def set_errors(record, attribute, errors)
    unless errors.empty?
      if options[:message]
        record.errors[attribute] = options[:message]
      else
        record.errors[attribute] += errors
      end
    end
  end

end
```

This validator does not work, because Rails does not pass it the
original string value of the attribute.  Instead, Rails converts the
string to a time object before calling the validator.  If the string
cannot be converted, it passes nil to the validator:

```
Job.new(run_time: "ABC").save
# [nilClass, nil]
```

If the string can be converted, it passes a time object to the
validator:

```
Job.new(run_time: "01/01/2014").save
# [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, Wed, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 UTC +00:00]
```

**When validating a timestamp attribute, how can a custom validator
get access to the original string value of the attribute?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `run_time_before_type_cast`?

In your validator you could use something like `record.send "#{attribute}_before_type_cast"`